# Homomorphism. Equation.

Tags: monoid

Let $h$ be a homomorphism monoid $M =\{0,1\}^*$  $h: M \to M, h(0) = 1, h(1) = 010$
And it is true:
$h^3(1^+) = (h(1)h(1)h(1) )^+ $
I don't understand this equation.

Comment: What is this bunch of symbols? It seems that you are working with the free monoid with two generators, but what is $1^+$?

Comment: @Crostul: It's only my guess, but in formal languages regular expression $1^+$ means any finite sequence of 1's of positive length.

Comment: user35603 is right. I am working with free monoid in regular language.

Comment: @Crostul: I guess this is standard notation imported from the theory of regular expressions: $x^+$ means $x^n, n \ge 1$.

Comment: There is something wrong in $h(0) = , h(1) = 010$. Please correct.

Comment: corrected. Sorry for problems.

Comment: May be it shout be "And is it true" instead of "And it is true"?

Comment: This formula was given as truth. I am not sure, so I am asking for.

Comment: Are you sure that $h(0)=1$? Or $h(0)=\varepsilon$, where $\varepsilon$ in the empty word?

Comment: Yes, I am sure of that fact.

Comment: Ok, consider a word "$1$". So, according to the equation we should obtain $$h^3(1)=h(1)h(1)h(1).$$

We have
$$h^3(1)=h^2(h(1))=h^2(010)=h(h(0)h(1)h(0))=\\
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad=h(1\:010\:1)=h(1)h(0)h(1)h(0)h(1)=h(1)\:1\:h(1)\:1\:h(1).$$

Comment: I am not sure if it is true:
$h^3(1)=h^2(h(1))$

Comment: When you write $h^3$, does this mean $h \circ h \circ h$ (composition of functions)?

Comment: I mean $h(1)^3 = h(1)h(1)h(1)$, co concatenation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the clarifications in the comments below the question, I understand your question as follows: is it true that $\Big( h(1^+) \Big)^3 = \Big( h(1)^3 \Big) ^+$? For mathematicians not accustomed with notations from formal languages, this can be reread as: is it true that for every $n \ge 1$ there exist $m \ge 1$ such that $\Big( h(1^n) \Big)^3 = \Big( h(1)^3 \Big) ^m$? Let us prove the statement by induction on $n$: clearly it is true for $n=1$ (just choose $m=1$); for $n>1$

$$\Big( h(1^{n+1}) \Big)^3 = \Big( h(1^n 1) \Big)^3 = \Big( h(1^n) h(1) \Big)^3 = h(1^n) h(1) h(1^n) h(1) h(1^n) h(1)= h(1)^m h(1) h(1)^m h(1) h(1)^m h(1) = h(1)^{3m+3} .$$

In fact, one can do even better: the above proof shows that the dependence of $m$ on $n$ can be given recursively by $m(n+1) = 3 m(n), \space m(1)=1$. This gives $m(n) = 3^{n-1}$, so we can be even more precise: $\Big( h(1^n) \Big) ^3 = \Big( h(1) \Big)^{3^{n-1}}$.